# Plugin 'Database Navigator' (version '3.4.1220.0') is not compatible

Tags: database, postgresql

Plugin 'Database Navigator' (version '3.4.1220.0') is not compatible with the current version of the IDE, because it requires build 232.* or older but the current build is IC-233.14015.106 Plugin 'Lombok' (version '232.9921.47') is not compatible with the current version of the IDE, because it requires build 232.* or older but the current build is IC-233.14015.106. how to solve this problem.

I wanted to interact with Database Navigator in Springboot

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me and fixed the error 100%

Check for Plugin Updates:

- Go to "Settings" > "Plugins" in IntelliJ IDEA.
- Look for the plugins "Database Navigator" and "Lombok."
  -  Check if there are updates available for these plugins. If updates are available, install them